# Can connect to app locally but not remotely

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am following the sample application here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-data-aggregation

When I build and deploy the application to my local cluster and access it using this url: http://localhost:8505/index.html, it works.

However, when i deploy it on a service cluster I set up in the cloud and try and access the same page with this url: http://[some_name].southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:8505/index.html, it fails.

What am i missing here?

Comment: u didnt provide enough information for the community to help you.

Comment: Honestly, im not sure what else I can offer. I made no changes to the codebase at all. I simply published the application

Comment: How exactly it fails? Why do you use :8085?

Comment: It fails by displaying "This site can’t be reached" on the page. Im using 8505 because of the following line in the WebServices's ServiceManifest.xml file : <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="http" Port="8505" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to add a load balancer rule? More info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services.md).
Chapter:

```
Connections from external clients
```

Comment: Yup, this is it. Silly me for missing this